# Angular textarea newline not working when ng-model is changed

Tags: angularjs, textarea

I have a text area bound to a variable in the controller using ngModel. The problem is only the initialized value is displayed in the textarea with proper new line formatting . When I change value of the model that has \n, it shows the text \n rather than the expected new line. Has anyone encountered this before? I'm using Angular 1.2.28

**Controller**

```
ctrlFunction = function () {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    templateUrl: 'my/view/path.html',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.text = '\nLOOP 100\n  WAIT 5\n  input hello\n  if 1\n    message\n  endif\nENDLOOP\nHANGUP\n\n\n\u0000';

        scope.changeText= function(){
                 scope.text='\nLOOP 100\n  WAIT 5\n  input hello\n  if 1\n    message\n  endif\nENDLOOP\nHANGUP\n\n\n\u0000';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
  <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="text"></textarea>
  <button ng-click="changeText()"></button>
```

**Before clicking the button**
[image]

**After**
[image]

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention `"&#13;" or "<br />"` did not work either. In fact they did not work even during the initialization of the model

Comment: what if you use ascii code 13 instead of \n?

Comment: same, instead of \n it is showing &#13; @user1697575

Comment: replace `\n` with `<br/>`. OR `<pre>{{ text }}</pre>` in that place

Comment: @latheefitzmeontv itzmeontv : Please note , its not possible to assign html values to text area usng ng-model

Comment: oh, then i think `ng-bind`, here may be `ng-bind-html` can use?

Comment: This may help you https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your problem but if you are trying to display the text with `\n` characters as newlines you can put the expression into an element with `style="white-space: pre;"`

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('myTextArea', function() {
  var startingText = "Starting text";
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    template: '<textarea class="form-control" ng-model="text"></textarea><div style="white-space: pre;">{{ text }}</div><div><button ng-click="changeText()">change</button></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.text = startingText;
      scope.changeText = function() {
        scope.text = '\nLOOP 100\n  WAIT 5\n  input hello\n  if 1\n    message\n  endif\nENDLOOP\nHANGUP\n\n\n\u0000';
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```css
textarea.form-control {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app'>
  <my-text-area></my-text-area>
</div>
```